# php echo string too long

Tags: php, string, config, nagle

I'm not sure if this is a php bug or server config but I can't seem to echo strings much over 2,000,000 characters in length. The page just hangs.

This works on my local machine but not on my live server.

```
$data = '';

for($i = 0; $i < 3000000; $i++) {
    $data .= 1;
}

echo $data;
```

I've tried using str_split to break up the string into an array and output each portion individually but it still won't do it.

I've also seen some comments about this having to do with Nagle's Algorithm and TCP/IP buffering but I'm still none the wiser.

Please help!

Comment: because of this for($i = 0; $i < 3000000; $i++) { u r concatenating the value, it will run untill complete the range of <3000000

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm purposefully concatenating the value to create a very long string to illustrate the issue.

Comment: What is the size of the data coming back when you do it on your local server? You should be able to see that in the Net tab of the developer tools.

Comment: Locally I can up the loops to well over 5000000, I've not really found a limit. But on the live server it gets to around 2000000 loops (2MB of data) before it hangs indefinitely.

Comment: Very strangely if I visit the page on an iphone it loads without an issue!

Comment: either you max out the max execution time or the string get over 2GB, imo

Comment: Those were my initial thoughts but the data is about 3mb, and the my max execution time is 120 seconds. On mobile on the same network the page loads in about 1 second. I'm at a loss.

Comment: This looks to some kind of php/apache buffering issue.

I've not managed to find out the definitive answer for this yet, but a workaround is to calculate the page content size and add it to the header info.